# Slider Revolution images with different height

Tags: jquery, revolution-slider

I have slider revolution set up on a project and I'm facing a technical issue. The slider will be displaying images of different sizes. The property `startheight` allow me to set the slider height but I need that the height change according the height of the image that is being displayed. I have this code to initialize the plugin:

```
$(this).show().revolution({
            delay:2000,
            startheight: 500,
            autoHeight: "on",

            navigationType:"bullet",
            navigationArrows:"solo",

            navigationStyle:"round",

            navigationHAlign:"center",
            navigationVAlign:"bottom",
            navigationVOffset:20,

            touchenabled:"on",
            onHoverStop:"on",

            shadow:1
        });
```

The `autoHeight` property doesn't make any difference and if I remove `startheight` it shows a default height, 333px I think. How can I make this that the height change as in any other slider?

Comment: A hack would be setting your image height to 500px and width to auto in your css

Comment: @user3791775 Agreed. But I doubt the client want a non full size image in the slider spot :(

Comment: @user3791775 So it's not possible to make it dynamic? This must be the first slider I see with a fixed height. I may be missing the revolution part. My client has images with different sizes, so it seems I'm going to waste a lot of time implementing another slider and giving up slider revolution :(

Comment: I don t know revolution. If you are going for the dynamic view you will get a lot of vertical changes